# PRETTIER FORMATTER: How to allow prettier only for some files and folders. (This question is about allowing prettier, not about disabling it.)

Tags: prettier

In Prettier code formatter, it is easy to disable Prettier for some files and folders with **.prettierignore** file. Is it possible to work the other way round? Is it possible to disable Prettier and allow it only for some files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can *negate* patterns on `.prettierignore`. For example, run only on `src` folder:

```
!src/**/*
```